# Selected effect around an item in QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt

The "selected effect" (the one you get when you use TAB) is always present in my QTreeWidget when I set the selection mode to ExtendSelection (I need it to be able to select multiple items).

The effect is gone if I remove this line from the code :

```
 ui->treeWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
```

How can I remove it while keeping the ExetendSelection? Here is the picture. (To be clear, what I don't want is the border effect around the item "Amis")

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2NYV.png)

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a custom delegate that will override a `paint` method.

Answer (score 1):

As **SaZ** said, you have to use a custom *delegate* with the overridden `paint()` method.

In my projects I use this approach:

```
void CMyDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);

    // This solves your problem - it removes a "focus rectangle".
    if (itemOption.state & QStyle::State_HasFocus)
        itemOption.state = itemOption.state ^ QStyle::State_HasFocus;

    initStyleOption(&itemOption, index);

    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &itemOption, painter, nullptr);
}
```

In the previous example, `CMyDelegate` was derived from the `QStyledItemDelegate`. You can also derive from the `QItemDelegate` and your `paint()` method will look like this:

```
void CMyDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);

    // This solves your problem - it removes a "focus rectangle".
    if (itemOption.state & QStyle::State_HasFocus)
        itemOption.state = itemOption.state ^ QStyle::State_HasFocus;

    QItemDelegate::paint(painter, itemOption, index);
}
```

And this is how to use the custom delegate:

```
CMyDelegate* delegate = new CMyDelegate(treeWidget);
treeWidget->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```